# Partitions for loop device not found from script, visible elsewhere

Tags: partition, parted, disk-image, loop-device, mkfs

I'm currently trying to partition and then format a disk image using `parted`, by first mounting a blank disk image onto a loop, creating the appropriate partitions, and then formatting these partitions using `mkfs`, like below:

```
# Create and loop a blank image.
touch disk.img
truncate disk.img --size 6G
disk_loop=$(sudo losetup -Pf disk.img --show)
echo "Loop at $disk_loop."

# Set up partitions.
sudo parted $disk_loop mklabel gpt mkpart primary fat32 4MiB 516MiB mkpart primary ext4 516MiB 6143MiB
```

After this point, I have then tried to format the created partitions using `mkfs.fat` and `mkfs.ext4` respectively, however these both fail as they cannot find the partitions at `/dev/loopNp1` or `/dev/loopNp2`:

```
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.fat: unable to open '/dev/loop32p1': No such file or directory
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The file '/dev/loop32p2' does not exist and no size was specified.
```

I thought this may be a problem with the loop simply not having set up these partitions yet, so I tried the following:

- Performing a `partprobe` on the device with `partprobe /dev/loopN` before formatting.
- Doing the above, and also sleeping for 5-20 seconds beforehand.
- Adding the partitions with `partx -v -a /dev/loopN`, which complains that the device or resource is busy.

During the sleep time, I also opened another console window and performed `ls /dev`, which showed that the partitions at `/dev/loopNp1` and `/dev/loopNp2` were indeed created and visible, however they could not be found after the sleep within the script. What am I overlooking here, and how can I make these partitions available before formatting?

Some example script output:

```
... prior script output, then fdisk -l /dev/loop0 is called ...
 
Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/loop0p1    8192  1056767  1048576  512M Microsoft basic data
/dev/loop0p2 1056768 12580863 11524096  5.5G Linux filesystem
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.fat: unable to open '/dev/loop0p1': No such file or directory
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The file '/dev/loop0p2' does not exist and no size was specified.
```

Comment: for `N=0` it works for me as expected; I get `/dev/loop0p1` and `/dev/loop0p2` almost instantly after the `parted`. This on a Pi running Raspbian 10 (buster). On repeating the process I found I also needed `rm -f disk.img` before the `truncate` so that `mkpart` - and potentially the kernel - didn't see an existing partition table and create the subdevices immediately that `losetup` was invoked

Comment: Thanks roaima - I just tried this with a fresh boot & wiping the image beforehand with `rm -f`, but I seem to be getting the same result. I can see the partition loops pop up almost immediately with `ls`, but for some reason within the script it appears to not exist.

Comment: Does your script (inadvertently) reference `/dev/loop0` instead of the device you've assigned through `$disk_loop`? I notice your error message refers to `/dev/loop32`, which suggests you've a lot of previous attempts still hanging around

Comment: Updates don't belong in comments. I've copied your pastebin to the question so it can be easily seen by anyone wanting to help you

Comment: What abut syslog? Sometime the AI named `systemd` works against the operator.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `qemu-nbd` instead:

```
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 disk.img
```

Comment: Interestingly this seems to suffer from the exact same issue - I have switched to using `/dev/nbd0` and then check whether the file exists in bash with `if [! -f /dev/nbd0p1]` after partitioning with `parted`, and it thinks the file does not exist. Likewise, `mkfs` does not recognise it either. Strange.